# Does PL/SQL Procedure Automatically Commit When it Exits?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle12c

I have a cursor in a stored procedure (Oracle 12.1 PL/SQL) that gets a list of records, and it iterates through the collection, and updates 500 records in bulk at the time. These updates do not dependent on each other.

My question is, if the stored procedure does not commit anything explicitly, when it exists, does it commit the transaction on its own? The reason I ask is that my data set is big and once it is updated, it makes it very difficult to revert it with data fix, so I want to make sure whether the commit does not happen when I invoke it from SQL Developer (just want to time the execution).

Comment: @Turo I found that question afterward, but you are. Looks like mine is a duplicate. Thanks.